# Macro making of the content of lhead and rhead

Tags: macros, header-footer, exam

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{exam}

\lhead{\fbox{\textbf{LEFT}}}
\newcommand[\macrol]{\lhead{\fbox{\textbf{LEFT}}}} 

\rhead{\fbox{\textbf{RIGHT}}}
\newcommand[\macrol]{\lhead{\fbox{\textbf{RIGHT}}}}

\begin{document}
First Page
\newpage

The content of lhead is \macrol.

The content of rhead is  \macror.

\end{document}
```

My purpose is to call `\lhead` or `\rhead` from anywhere in the text with a macro.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you want. There's no problem to put a macro inside the `\lhead` command.  How do you want the choice to be made?

Comment: I apologize for not telling you exactly. I edited the problem and added new image. Can you check?

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't understand. Do you want to define a macro that saves the value of \lhead and \rhead which can then be used in the document.

Comment: I want to write that I'm sorry again. No I do not want to define a macro without saving the `\lhead` and `\rhead` values ​​that can be used later on the document. I want to define a macro but this macro will be to read the contents of `\lhead` and `\rhead`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple way to do what you want:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{exam}
\newcommand\savelhead[1]{\gdef\savedlhead{#1}\lhead{\savedlhead}}
\newcommand\saverhead[1]{\gdef\savedrhead{#1}\rhead{\savedrhead}}
\savelhead{LeftHead}
\saverhead{RightHead}

\begin{document}
First Page
\newpage
Booklet Choice \savedlhead\ or \savedrhead.
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: The explanation you wrote provided me with good information.

Comment: @Özgür if the answer helped you it's helpful to "Accept" it by clicking on the green checkmark beside it.

Comment: I edited the problem. Can you check?

Comment: I took your precious time.